# Installing Arch Linux alongside OS X - Bootloader issues

Tags: arch-linux, osx, grub2, dual-boot, boot-loader

I have installed Arch Linux alongside my OS X install on my MBP 11,1 using the guide found [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBookPro11,x), however on the last three commands of the [boot loader section](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBookPro11,x#Using_the_MacBook.27s_native_EFI_bootloader) I get the error

`/usr/sbin/grub2-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of 'rootfs'`

Thus when I attempt to boot my Linux partition I get the error

`error: file '/vmlinuz-linux' not found.
out of range pointer 0x20`

Here is my partition setup:

`/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         80.7 GB    disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS disk0s4                 134.2 MB   disk0s4
   5: 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4               209.7 MB   disk0s5
   6: 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4               12.9 GB    disk0s6
   7: 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4               26.4 GB    disk0s7
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS OS X                   *80.3 GB    disk1`

Anyone know how I can fix my bootloader setup to work? Or a different setup that would be better suited for my setup?

Comment: did you ever get this resolved?